# Why i can't compare CString in MFC

Tags: mfc, cstring

This line.

```
UpdateData(true);
if( m_OldPassword.Compare(d.pass) && m_NewPassword.Compare(m_ConfirmPassword) )
```

m_OldPassword, m_NewPassword, m_ConfirmPassword

is variable i added from EditControl

`m_OldPassword.Compare(d.pass)` Result =true (tested)

`m_NewPassword.Compare(m_ConfirmPassword)` Result = false.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(ChangePassword, CDialog)

ChangePassword::ChangePassword(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(ChangePassword::IDD, pParent)
    , m_OldPassword(_T(""))
    , m_NewPassword(_T(""))
    , m_ConfirmPassword(_T(""))
{
}
```

I dont know what's happen. I sure my input(new, confirm) is right.

Comment: We need to see the code before that line. Specifically, how all your variables were assigned

Comment: `CString::Compare` returns `0` **on equality**!

Comment: Only Updatedata before that line. see my update

Comment: Glad you mentioned UpdateData, that was my first thought. And @BeyelerStudios is right, the return value is *not* a boolean and you can't treat it as such. See the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314313%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: Did you *read* the documentation? The problem should be obvious, and I don't feel like writing your code for you.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

```
if( m_OldPassword.Compare(d.pass)==0 && m_NewPassword.Compare(m_ConfirmPassword)==0 )
```

if you are comparing two Cstring say `abc` and `xyz`
 if abc equal to the string xyz it will return 0
 if abc greater than the string xyz it will return 1
 if abc less than the string xyz it will return -1