# How i can get value from Edit control from other form MFC

Tags: mfc, compare

file DoAnMFC.h

```
public:
    CString user;
    CString pass;
    bool isAdmin;
    bool isLogin;
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedLoginBtn();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedCancleBtn();
    afx_msg void showwithAdmin();
    afx_msg void showwithEmployee();
    afx_msg void ghiLog();
    afx_msg bool CheckLogin(CString username,CString password);
    CListCtrl m_ListControl;
    CEdit m_EditControl;
    afx_msg void OnSystemChangepassword();
    afx_msg void OnSystemExit();
    afx_msg void OnToolsCreateaccount();
    afx_msg void OnToolsEditaccount();
    afx_msg void OnToolsFindaccount();
    afx_msg void OnToolsDeleteaccount();
    CEdit m_ControlUser;
    CEdit m_ControlPassword;
```

This is event click a button to change Password

```
void ChangePassword::OnBnClickedOkBtn()
    {
        UpdateData(true);
        CDoAnMFCDlg d;
        CString loginPassword;
        d.m_ControlPassword.GetWindowText(loginPassword);
        if( d.pass.Compare(loginPassword)==0 && m_NewPassword.Compare(m_ConfirmPassword)==0 )
            {...........}
    }
```

How to compare data form ChangePassword with data from form DoAnFMC ? This line have result is false

```
d.pass.Compare(loginPassword)==0
```

Comment: You can't use just *any* dialog object to get the value, you must use the exact dialog object that was shown to the user. And it must still be active, or the call will fail.

Comment: How i can use variable "pass" in form ChangePassword ?

Comment: Your understanding of how things work is so far off that I'm not sure I can help you.

Comment: There is no example. The proper way to do things is from within the active dialog itself, or from a dialog that you created locally after `DoModal` has returned `ID_OK`. To get a value from one dialog into another completely disassociated dialog is not something people usually do.

Comment: It working fine in my system, I think you are not getting value of CString `pass`. Try to print value of `d.pass` in a message box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why i can't compare CString in MFC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273176/why-i-cant-compare-cstring-in-mfc)